# Creating render urls to link between pages in a community in Liferay

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, taglib, jsr168

I've set up a Liferay community, along with a number of pages each defining there own set of portlets, themes and layouts. I want to be able to create links between these pages. For example given that I am at the top level page (lets call this 'home'), I want to link to another page (for example 'blog') from within one of my portlets.

Is there a way, either using the Liferay or Portlet APIs to create a render url based on a page parameter that I supply. As far as I can see, the liferay-portlet-ext taglib defines a renderUrl tag that I can use to create a URL that links back to the same page, however I can't see a way to specify the page name in this tag.

I'm using Liferay 5.2.3. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either link them with friendlyURLs (/web/othergroup/blog) or you can use

```
PortletURL portletURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(
    request, portletName, plid, ‎lifecycle);‎
```

Comment: portletName in the above code is named wrong in Liferay. Deep down it gets assigned to variable named protletId and portletId is what you actually need to pass for it.